# Rigorous definition of generalized coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, topology, constrained-dynamics

In Goldstein's classical mechanics and in many other books I haven't seen a rigorous definition of [generalized coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates).

In a system of $N$ particles described by $\textbf{r}_1, \dots, \textbf{r}_N$ It is said that some variables $q_1, \dots , q_n $ are generalized coordinates if we can express:

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\textbf{r}_1 & = & \textbf{r}_1(q_1,\dots,q_n,t)\\
& \vdots & \\
\textbf{r}_N & = & \textbf{r}_N(q_1,\dots,q_n,t)\\
\end{array} \tag{1.38}
\end{equation}

and viceversa, we can express $q_1,\dots,q_n$ in terms of $\textbf{r}_1,\dots,\textbf{r}_N$ i.e., this transformation must be bijective.

Nevertheless nothing is said about the regularity of this transformation.

Does this transformation need to be a diffeomorphism, just a differentiable homeomorphism or what do we need to ask for?

Comment: Perhaps you want to read a text that includes more mathematical details. One standard such book is by V. Arnold ("Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics").

Comment: I have looked for the answer in this book too, but miraculously seems to find the way to avoid the treatment of this question.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with Pfaffian systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration space of $N$ points  is obtained by assuming that the $C< 3N$ constraints are *functionally independent* at every fixed time. The implicit function theorem (or regular value theorem) implies that the configuration space is a $n$ dimensional manifold, an embedded submanifold of $R^{3N}$, where $n= 3N-C$. Lagrangian coordinates are nothing but any local coordinate patch.
If the constraint equations are expressed by means of functions of regularity class $C^k$, the arising manifold has the same degree of regularity. Hence the Lagrangian coordinates are of class $C^k$ as well.

Comment: How do you define a diffeomorphism when $\textbf{r}_1,\dots,\textbf{r}_N$ are defined in a non open set (such a sphere)?                                                                                   Maybe you are implicitly saying that the set where $\textbf{r}_1,\dots,\textbf{r}_N$ move is a differentiable manifold (say a sphere), but in that case I know every homeomorphism into, in this case, a sphere defines a differentiable structure

Comment: I wrote into an explicit form my previous sloppy answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But related to that I have now a new question. If for example your configuration space is $\mathbb{R}^4$ It is known that you can endow this space with more than one differential structures wich are not diffeomorphic (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4). In that case, could you obtain using different differential structures, i.e., different generalized coordinates, different Lagrange equations, wich are not equivalent (since there is not a local diffeomorphism between coordinates)?

Comment: Different differentiable structures exist for $R^4$ on. In this case the physical space of a particle one starts with is $R^3$, and that of $N$ particles is a $N$ times Cartesian product of it. (Constraints have to be imposed in that space). So I do not think the use of exotic structures has any physical sense.